# place a vuetify slot outside of its component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to put the headers for a vuetify v1.5 `v-data-table` component outside of the data table component itself. Does anyone know how to achieve this? The below does not work:

```
<template>

    <div>  
        <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props"> 
            <th
                v-for="header in props.headers"
                :key="header.text"
                :class="['table-header']">

                {{ header.text }}
            </th>          
        </template>
    </div>

    //some other unrelated code

    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        class="elevation-1"
        >
        <template v-slot:items="props">
            <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </template>
   </v-data-table>

</template>
```

Comment: Looking at your code I don't get what you present. Can you add more explanation?

Comment: I have a parent table with a bunch of subtables inside it. i want to show one of the subtables headers on top of the parent table

Comment: Hmm... how about create another (the same) table above, use `scopedSlots` to render headers and nothing for items?

Comment: those subtables each have different data, how does your proposed table know which table to become

Comment: @AdamOrlov could you show me how to do this in an answer please?

Comment: I read scoped slots but to me , coming from React, I don't understand what is the difference between slots and just child components, too complicated

Comment: Maybe vue-portal could be of interest for you. It let's you define an outlet (e.g. a position in the dom) where content of another component should be rendered.

Comment: tried vue-portal , was very hopeful, but would not work, I'm guessing it has some limitations around slots

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand right, let me know in a comment if my unswer is not what you meant.

**Proposition**: Create one `v-data-table` with all your headers and data. And above it another `v-data-table` with just headers.

See how it works in a [codepen - v-data-tables](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/rNaGzEj?editors=1010)

```js
// v-data-table - with items
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
   :items="desserts"
   class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:items="props">
    <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

```js
// v-data-table - just headers
<v-data-table
 :headers="headers"
 :items="desserts"
 class="elevation-1"
 hide-actions
></v-data-table>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'left',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name'
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%'
      },
    ],
  },
}
```